# GoJS highlightCollection is not working for date value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, date, gojs

I highlight one or many nodes, edges and properties in my graph with the 'highlightCollection' method and it works great, except for the date values.

Here is what I tried:

When the value '2013-01-28' is in the field 'dateValue' of a Link (edge) or a Node Property:

2013
**Found**

2013-01-28
**Not found**

2013-
**Not found**

As soon as there is a dash in the search string, the property is not found by the 'highlightCollection' method.

When the same value '2013-01-28' is in the field 'textValue' of a Link or a Node Property:

2013 
**Found**

2013-01-28 
**Found**

2013- 
**Found**

I tried with no regex at all and with this one, that completely doesn't care about the dash, or any character that can be inside the date value :

`/2013.{0,}03.{0,}25/`

Does GoJS modify or analyze the date value in a different manner when it's a date? Is the field 'dateValue' a reserved word?

We are currently working on the version 1.6.23

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data property value is a **Date**, **Diagram.findNodesByExample** will evaluate `regex.test(dataPropertyValue.toString())`.  So the result depends on what **toString** returns for **Date**s.

In Firefox `new Date().toString()` returns "Wed Jun 14 2017 16:30:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)" for me, just a moment ago, so I can see why adding a hyphen/dash to the search string would cause it to fail.

Instead of using a **Regex**, you could use a function as a predicate that does whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

It was exactly that, when a make a new date from the date I search and I search for this text, the 'highlightCollection' method returns the right items.

Thanks a lot!